# update a single database field in cakephp - SHOULD BE SIMPLE

Tags: cakephp

Hey guys, I'm trying to create a 'booking confirmed' link, that when clicked changes the table field 'confirmed' from 0 to 1.

so far I've got:

```
function admin_markAsConfirmed($id = null) {
    $this - > Booking - > id = $id;
    if ($this - > Booking - > saveField('confirmed', 1)) {
        $this - > Session - > setFlash('Booking Confirmed');
        $this - > redirect(array('action' = > 'admin_index'));
    }
}
```

But it's not working. All this does is insert a new row, instead of editing the row specified by $id.

How do I make this work? It seems so simple but I've been stuck for a good few hours on this.

Comment: Did you check whether ID is actually being set?

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like this...

```
$this->Post->id = 1;<br/>
$this->Post->read();<br/>
$this->Post->set('title', 'New title for the article');<br/>
$this->Post->save();
```

Here is the [link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html) to the Cake book online

Comment: Add $this->Article->read(); after $this->Booking->id = $id;  I don't think setting the id actually does anything until you call a find or a read method.

Comment: @MarkFruhling nonsense. For the code in the question to not work, `$id` is not what the OP thinks or there is other unshown code that's interfering.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Update field to desired value
$data = array( 'someModel' => array( 'id' => $this->someModel->id, 'someField' => 'someInfo' ) );

// Save the changes
$this->someModel->save( $data, false, array('someField') );
```